# Display all the local storage where the key is unknown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, local-storage

I have an HTML form. When you submit the form.
It's create a localstorage with Key = date and hours and the value = the data of the form.

How can I display all my localstorage? (I don't know the name of the key so)
and export all the localstorage to a txt file

Comment: With 'export all the localstorage to a txt file' you mean just once copy and paste the values, or bind the export to the submit, so that every time you submit the values the txt gets created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the full content of the localStorage by typing `localStorage` into your devtools console, or directly use `window.localStorage` variable in your code

On chrome devtools, you can also go to Applications > Storage > Local Storage (on the left)

Comment: I don't want to show this into a console. I want export all localstorage to txt

Comment: Copy paste it from the console into a txt file ;)

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` has a `length` property counting the number of existing `keys`. For each of these `key` there is an `item` accessible trough the `getItem` method.

*Try the following code in the console as here it is sandboxed and localStorage is not accessible.*

```js
var ls = top.localStorage,
  n = ls.length,
  i = 0,
  key, value;

console.log('There are ', n, 'items in the localStorage');

for (; i < n; i++) {
  key = ls.key(i);
  value = ls.getItem(key);
  console.log('key: ', key, 'value:', value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

```js
var data = localStorage;

for(var key in data){

  console.log(key, data[key]);

}
```

data will have key value pairs. using `for in loop` you can iterate through data and access.

Comment: I don't want to show this into a console. I want export all localstorage to txt

Comment: You mean you what data as text file? @F.Vandroy

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can store all the data from `localStorage` to variable then save it as a text file, from the download link.

```js
var downloadlink = document.getElementById('download');
var text = '';
for(var key in localStorage) {
  text += localStorage.getItem(key).toString();
}

var file = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});
downloadlink.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
downloadlink.download = 'localStorageData.txt';
```

```html
<a id="download" href="">Download</a>
```

Try with for loop

```
for(var key in localStorage) {
   console.log('key: ', key);
   console.log('data: ', localStorage.getItem(key));
}
```

Comment: I don't want to show this into a console. I want export all localstorage to txt